# In prototype how to remove li from ul

Tags: prototype

html

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <input type="hidden" name="cur-sym" id="cur-sym" value="£">
     <li class="price-was"><span id="new-price-2157-span">Was</span> <span id="new-price-2157">£100.00</span></li>

     <li class="price-save" id="price-save"><span>You save </span>£50.00</li>
</ul>
```

I want to remove `<li>` from ul if it exists

I'm trying with this code to remove `li`:

```
if($('li.price-was')!=undefined)
    {   
        $( "li.price-was" ).remove();
        $( "li.price-save" ).remove(); 
    }
```

but using this code is not working. So how to remove `li`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Question use class for remove element so that Only `$` is use for `id`.If u want to use `classname` than u have to use `$$`

```
    if($$('li.price-was')!=undefined)
    {   
        $$( "li.price-was" ).each(Element.remove);
        $$( "li.price-save" ).each(Element.remove);
    }
```

This is work for me to remove `li` from `ul` using `prototype`